# Ebean & Play Framework 2.3.8 : Missing statements

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3

I am working with Play Framework 2.3.8 (Java) and Ebean.
My project grows fine and I am now looking for solutions to catch an advanced information from my database .

But, I can't find a way to use the "count()" statement or the "group by" statement. I've checked the ebean documentation but it doesn't mention this so my question is : Are these statements even included in ebean ? Or do I need to use something special for this kind of queries?

My query in SQL looks like this:

```
"select thing, COUNT(thing) as count from Table group by thing";
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I've tried "return find.select("thing, count(thing)").where().findList(); for the count() part, and got a "not found for the model" error.

I have no idea for the group by statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have 3 approaches, first (answered by Anton) with `SqlQuery`, second - unfortunately without access to alias fields, third - allows you to group and map your alias fields to `Transient` model fields as well.

```
    // First approach: returns list of `raw` rows so it's mpst flexible
    List<SqlRow> rows = Ebean
            .createSqlQuery("SELECT id, count(bar) AS bar_count FROM foo WHERE 1 GROUP BY bar")
            .findList();


    // Second uses `GROUP BY`, returns entities BUT without alias fields
    List<Foo> foos = Ebean
            .createQuery(Foo.class, "WHERE 1 GROUP BY bar")
            .select("id")
            .findList();

    // or just...
    List<Foo> foos2 = Foo
            .find.where("1 GROUP BY bar")
            .findList();

    // Third, returns entities, alias fields can be mapped to model as well (requires @Transient annotation for these fields in model)
    RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder
            .parse("SELECT id, count(bar) FROM foo WHERE 1 GROUP BY bar")
            .columnMapping("id", "id")
            .columnMapping("count(bar)", "bar_count")
            .create();

    com.avaje.ebean.Query<Foo> query = Ebean.find(Foo.class);
    query.setRawSql(rawSql);

    List<Foo> foosRaw = query.findList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlQuery.html

```
 String sql = "select thing, COUNT(thing) as count from Table group by :thing";

 SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
 sqlQuery.setParameter("thing", "FOO");

 // execute the query returning a List of MapBean objects
 List<SqlRow> list = sqlQuery.findList();
```

Then you can work with the `SqlRow`s in JDBC-fashion - getting integers, strings and so on...

Comment: Yeah ok, that's what I was afraid of, no group by statement defined directly in ebean. But, that's fine, it works. Thanks for your help ;)